# is there such a thing called "the degree of algebraic expression"? if so, then what would happen when consider the negative exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that for a polynomial, the degree is the highest exponent sum and it is a natural number.

Since polynomial is a case of algebraic expression, when consider other form of algebraic expression (such as irrational expression and rational fraction), is there such a thing can be referred as "the degree of algebraic expression"? If so, then how am I suppose to determine the degree of it when negative exponents appear in the expression?

Comment: " how am I suppose to determine the degree of it when negative exponents appear in the expression?"  Why would that be an issue?  The degree would be highest exponential power of $x$ in the expression.  There's no reason it can't be negative or a rational non-integer.

Comment: @fleablood, so if the absolute value of a negative exponent is greater than any positive exponent, I should still choose the highest postive exponent as the degree?

Comment: Yep. @rookie   $ $

Comment: Yes.  There is no significance to the absolute values of the powers and that is of no interest to us.  We take the highest power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One definition that is sometimes used is that the degree of a function $f(x)$ is given by

$$\text{degree}(f) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln | f(x) |}{\ln(x)}$$

For $x^r$, this nicely evaluates to $r$, even for non-integer $r$. You can also use this to see that, for $f$ that is the sum of such terms, whichever $r$ is the highest is the degree.

You can also use this for other functions, too, and find some degrees even if the function is not a polynomial in any realistic sense. For instance:

- $f(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$ has degree $1/2$
- $f(x) = e^{\sin(x)}$ has degree $0$

A bit more can be read on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Computed_from_the_function_values).